# Prisma.io ORM self-to-many relation generates unique key

Tags: javascript, express, orm, backend, prisma

I have been using **Prisma.io** for a while now and today I discovered that in one-to-many self relation it generates an **unique** key which **doesn't allow** my backend to work as expected at some point when I try to **connect multiple records to one**, it simply connects it to the newest.

I tried to **manually delete** the key (unprofessional, I know) but it still said it is **needed in a foreign key**.

**Has anyone encountered this problem before ?**
I am using **Prisma CLI: 2.27.0**

Comment: Could you provide more details about your problem? In particular, what your Prisma schema looks like, code for the query you're running and preferably an example of what the query is doing vs what you want the query to do.

Comment: I have solved the issue by marking the key as an index explicitly @@index[keyname], I think the unique index was made just because Prisma thought that must be unique !